# c language makefile err:Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_main", referenced from: 'main'

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, linker

I have 3 header files and 4 .c files in my c program,which are `code1.h` `code1.c`,`code2.h` `code2.c`,`code3.h` `code3.c`,and `main.c`

The `main` function was defined in `main.c`

The relationships between files are:
`main.c` includes `code1.h`,     `code1.h` includes `code2.h`    `code2.h` includes `code3.h`

I implemented a make file to compile and link them together.

But when the make file executed,it shows an error:

```
"_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

here is my make file:

```
objects= main.o code1.o middle.o
executable:$(objects)
     gcc-o  $(objects) -o executable

main.o: main.c
     gcc -c main.c 

code1.o:code1.h code1.c
     gcc -c code1.c

middle.o:code2.o code3.o
     gcc -o code2.o code3.o  -o middle.o

code2.o:code2.c code2.h
     gcc -c code2.c
code3.o:code3.h code3.c
     gcc -c code3.c
```

Comment: If the error is related to your makefile, please post your gcc invocation.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: shouldn't that be `main.o` instead of `main1.o`?

Comment: That rule for `middle.o` is wildly incorrect. The rule for `executable` appears to be trying to run `gcc-o` (which strikes me as odd). You also didn't tell us which of those bizarre/broken rules is the one that is running and causing the error (though I expect that it is the `middle.o` rule). Why do you even have `middle.o`?

Comment: @Aniket If he wants it to be used given that makefile, yes. That being said it isn't necessary at all since that is just a poorer version of a built-in rule that make already has (and the rule that make will be using currently to build `main.o` given that makefile above).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your makefile has some errors:
corrections :
#incorrectly placed main.o instead of main1.o

```
objects : main1.o code1.o middle.o
```

#rule for middle.o is incorrect.
correction -

```
middle.o : code2.o code3.o    
        gcc -o middle.o code2.o code3.o
```

#error in rule for executable : 
correction -

```
  executable : $(objects)
        gcc $(objects) -o executable
```

Reference for more detail on gnu Makefiles

```
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html
```

Comment: I fixed the second problem, and actually the first one you said above is correct in my original code.  But nothing changed after fixing it.

Comment: @user3788871 - error is still there in rule for "executable"   
correction :      
executable:$(objects)
gcc $(objects) -o executable

Comment: If you fixed your makefile locally then fix it in your post to match. We cannot help you if we don't have the actual file.

Comment: @user3788871 - check out this link on SO, hope it helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439664/what-does-the-the-compile-time-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64

Comment: @user3788871 - To my knowledge, its a linker error.
It means that you are calling a function for which you have not  
given any definition.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `objects` have the .o files like `main.o code1.o middle.o`. But the 1st target is wrongly named as `main1.o`. So the main.c file will not be compiled.

Comment: No, it will be compiled by the built-in `%.c: %.o` rule. You don't even need a makefile for make to be able to do that. Create a directory with just an empty file `foo.c` in it and then run `make foo.o` from that directory to see what I mean.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. The files names I posted are modified,and my original make file doesn't have this kind of error.