# What does "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" mean?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

So I changed the sqlite files (all three of them) that core data uses (I have done this numerous times without any problems) and all of a sudden I get this error and my project fails to compile:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can someone please help me understand what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is already covered here: [What does the the compile-time error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439664/what-does-the-the-compile-time-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64). Your code will first build (compile) and the it will try to link in all the code. It can't find "main" which is usually the entry/start point for an app.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did read that post. But how do I implement the "main" function. Furthermore, why did my app suddenly decide to not implement the "main" function on its own?

Comment: There are many things that could cause your project to no longer be able to find "main" to link to. Without posting the entire project (not possible here) it would be difficult to find the root cause. In ObjectiveC project there should be a file called "main.m" with a method "int main(int argc, char * argv[])". Somehow the project has lost track or something has been renamed and it can't be found. If your project is simple enough just create a brand new project and copy over whatever code/changes you've made and that might be easier.

Comment: @xdeleon FYI - In such cases you should vote to close a question as a duplicate instead of posting an answer that simply links to another question.

Comment: I found the problem. I only know Swift, "main" is AppDelegate.swift that file got deleted somehow (god only knows). Added the file and the project compiled. Thanks again.

Comment: @A.Jam You can post your own answer if you think it will help others or you can delete your question if not.