# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error:

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos

This is for a Mac using Eclipse

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 cout << "!!!Hello, world!!!" << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Here is the compiler output:

```
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker g++ -o "Lab2" ./secondlab.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_main", referenced from: implicit entry/start for main executable ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Lab2] Error 1
```

Comment: `clang` or `clang++`? Anyway, welcome to [so]. Please visit the [ask] help pages. Your question is very low on required details.

Comment: How does the compiler command line look?

Comment: This is the full error: Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++  -o "Lab2"  ./secondlab.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Lab2] Error 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I am unsure why I am getting this error, i am new to coding and cant figure it out, i did not have this issue when completing my last lab with the same IDE and compiler

Comment: Are you sure that source is actually part of your project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the compile-time error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86\_64" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8439664/608639)

Comment: It can't find your `main()` function because you haven't added the name of the file that you show into the compilation/link command. If your program that you show is in a file called `fred.cpp` you need to add `fred.cpp` to your `g++` command.

Answer (score -2):

All you need to do is configure the C++ Linker correctly under CDT/eclipse one has to enter "sndfile" in the text field found under:

> Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Mac OS C++
>   Linker->Libraries->"Libraries -l"

The **"-l"** gets added to "sndfile" automatically to create "-lsndfile"

It is also important however to point the Compiler to the correct include directory (containing "sndfile.h"). I guess most installations would install this into "/usr/local/include".
For a C++ project in CDT/eclipse, this would need to be entered in

> Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC C++
>   Compiler->Includes->"Include paths (-l)"

And please do take a look at [this](https://github.com/erikd/libsndfile/issues/45) thread.

Comment: Please don't just post a link as an answer, links expire then your answer becomes meaningless, post the important parts of your link inside your answer.